# Navigation link does not highlighting the current menu, when submenu is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have written jquery code for highlighting menu onclick of each `respective submenu`. Now here what happening is

I have one same link in three of the `sub-menu's`, so when I click one of them, it is highlighting the last menu.

Here is my code:-

```
var str = location.href.toLowerCase();
        $("#menu li a").each(function () {
            if (str.indexOf($(this).attr("href").toLowerCase()) > -1) {
                 $("li.activelink").removeClass("activelink");
                 $(this).parent().addClass("activelink");
                 $(this).parents("#menu ul").parent().addClass("activelink");
             }
         });
         $("li.activelink").parents().each(function () {
             if ($(this).is("li")) {
                 $(this).addClass("activelink");
             }
         });
         $("li.activelink").parents("#menu ul").parent().each(function () {
             if ($(this).is("li")) {
                 $(this).addClass("activelink");
             }
         });
         $("#menu li .para1 a").each(function () {
             if (str.indexOf($(this).attr("href").toLowerCase()) > -1) {
                 $("li.activelink").removeClass("activelink");
                 $(this).parent().addClass("activelink");
                 $(this).parents().parent().addClass("activelink");
             }
         });
         $("li.activelink").parents().each(function () {
             if ($(this).is("li")) {
                 $(this).addClass("activelink");
             }
         });
```

Have a look here

[image: Screenshot of the menu]

Also see the HTML of the same in the [Js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nadeem/arh3uoj6/1/)
Please suggest something for the same

Comment: Add the JS and CSS also in the fiddle to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @anpsmn: Updated js fiddle:- http://jsfiddle.net/nadeem/arh3uoj6/7/

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** This was not the OP intended question. The code below will not solve the problem.

I had this problem numerous times. Try this CSS code:

```
#menu > li:hover { background-color: red; }
```

Replace the background color declaration with your own highlight.

Comment: that is not my solution, please read my question what I am looking for. Highlighting the menu won't resolve my issue..Thanks